# API Gateway - Custom Authorizer was not working

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have run into some trouble configuring/using Authentication on AWS ApiGateway. I already have my lambda function set up with a code the receives the AWS authentication model, see below, which basically decodifies the JWT token and verifies if the given user can access the resource:

```
{
"type": "TOKEN",
"authorizationToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjotMTU1LCJwcm9kdWN0IjoiQmlsbGlvblJ1biIsInBlcm1pc3Npb25fbGV2ZWwiOjEsInNhbHQiOiJzZWNyZXRfcGhyYXNlIn0.3gZUFITe8or2mPWBAZlOxdcGF6-ybykHVsMRsqoUI_8",
"methodArn": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:123456789012:example/prod/POST/{proxy+}"
```

}

See below the sample outputs from ApiGateway documentation. The first one is when user is successfully verified (permission granted) and the second one is when user fails to verify (permission denied):

```
{
"principalId": "users",
"policyDocument": {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:REGION:AWS_ACCOUNT:example/prod/POST/{proxy+}"
        }
    ]
},
"context": {
    "user_id": XXX,
}
```

}

Permission denied:

```
{
"principalId": "users",
"policyDocument": {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:REGION:AWS_ACCOUNT:example/prod/POST/{proxy+}"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

The problem is: Every single time I test the custom authorization function, the return status is 200 (instead of 401) and the permission is granted (even when I send wrong tokens).

Also, I really feel like it is not even testing anything, although the screen shows that the custom authentication function is enabled.

[Resource showing custom authorizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mAR3.png)

[Inside resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtrSi.png)

[Custom Authorizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBdQ5.png)

[Invalid Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ly8k4.png)

[Valid Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dD7Lp.png)

------- EDIT -------

Here the code how I implemented the output:

```
def generate_policy(principal_id, effect, resource, context=None):
doc = {
    'principalId': principal_id,
    'policyDocument': {
        'Version': '2012-10-17',
        'Statement': [{
            'Action': 'execute-api:Invoke',
            'Effect': effect,
            'Resource': resource
        }]
    }
}
if context:
    doc["context"] = context
return doc
```

So you can call like this to "allow":

```
generate_policy("users", "Allow", method_arn, auth_info)
```

Or like this to "deny":

```
generate_policy("users", "Deny", method_arn)
```

-------- EDIT AGAIN ------
Gist with my all code:

https://gist.github.com/hermogenes-db18/1ccf3eb8273f266a3fa02643dcfd39bd

Comment: could you share your lambda authorizer code please?

Comment: Did you need how I was implemented my policy response?

Comment: yes because response attached in the screenshot does not seem correct.

Comment: @AtharKhan I edit original post

Comment: You've shared `generate_policy` function code, could you share full lambda authorizer code?

Comment: @A.Khan I edited again, please look at the gist.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

.Net Core (C#) version of Custom Authorizer

```cs
public class Function
{
    public AuthPolicy FunctionHandler(TokenAuthorizerContext request, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        var token = request.AuthorizationToken;
        var resourcePath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("resourcePath");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            return generatePolicy("user", "Deny", request.MethodArn);
        }

        AuthPolicy policy;
        var client = new HttpClient();

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", token);

        var dsresponse = client.GetAsync(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("validationURL")).Result;

        if (dsresponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            policy = generatePolicy("user", "Allow", resourcePath);
        }
        else
        {
            policy = generatePolicy("user", "Deny", resourcePath);
        }
        return policy;
    }

    private AuthPolicy generatePolicy(string principalId, string effect, string resourcePath)
    {
        AuthPolicy authResponse = new AuthPolicy();
        authResponse.policyDocument = new PolicyDocument();
        authResponse.policyDocument.Version = "2012-10-17";// default version
        authResponse.policyDocument.Statement = new Statement[1];

        Statement statement = new Statement();
        statement.Action = "execute-api:Invoke"; // default action
        statement.Effect = effect;
        statement.Resource = resourcePath;
        authResponse.policyDocument.Statement[0] = statement;
        return authResponse;
    }
}

public class TokenAuthorizerContext
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string AuthorizationToken { get; set; }
    public string MethodArn { get; set; }
}

public class AuthPolicy
{
    public PolicyDocument policyDocument { get; set; }
    public string principalId { get; set; }
}

public class PolicyDocument
{
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public Statement[] Statement { get; set; }
}

public class Statement
{
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Effect { get; set; }
    public string Resource { get; set; }
}
```

### Response

Request Denied:

```json
{
    "policyDocument": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                "Effect": "Deny",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-2:AccountId:API_Id/*"
            }
        ]
    },
    "principalId": null
}
```

Request Allowed:

```json
{
    "policyDocument": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-2:AccountId:API_Id/*"
            }
        ]
    },
    "principalId": null
}
```

Comment: Can you put here one sample of output? So I can fix my code, because I don't know C#. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of tests I finally found something that works! Even that all the documentation says to return a policy with "Deny", it seems that the only way to trigger an "Unauthorized 401" error is by including "callback" in the Authorizer parameter (something that seems deprecated but...) and using it like this:

```
exports.authorizer = (event, context, callback) => {

  if (invalidToken) {
    callback("Unauthorized", null);
  }

  // create a valid policy

  return validPolicy
}
```